# Ruby and system input

Tags: ruby

I have a command which is run with the system command.
Could I log what is passed to the shell?

P.S. I've got the problems with qoutes =)

Comment: What do you mean with "what is passed"? the result that the system command returns?

Comment: The exact string that will be called in shell

Comment: Do you want to capture the output of the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned having "the problem with the quotes".  I assume you mean double quotes?  Modify Vapire's solution to this:

```
command = %Q{echo "double quoted string"}  # store the command as string
puts command                               # print it before you execute it
system(command)                            # execute it in the shell
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply print the string before you're sending it to system command

```
command = "whoami"  # store the command as string
puts command        # print it before you execute it
system(command)     # execute it in the shell
```